# Ubuntu (22.04.03 LTS) freezes randomly - how to debug?

Tags: 22.04, freeze

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and from time to time it happens that the system freezes completely. No input works (escape, ctrl + alt + delete, etc.), no app reacts. The only way out is to forcefully reboot my PC. How can I figure out the root cause for this? Any logs that I can check?

Apps that are typically running when this happens: Vivaldi, Discord, Spotify, sometimes also Steam or Heroic Launcher. I built my PC back in November and I did a full pass of memtest86 with XMP activated, so I don't think it's my memory. Though I can check again if that could help. And the NVME SSD is new as well with plenty of space.

Comment: Are you sure that "no input works [...] no app reacts" or that merely the graphics are frozen? If you SSH in from another computer before the freeze, does the SSH respond? Also, did you look in `journalctl -r`?

Comment: @DanielT I just found out there's the Alt + SysRq + REISUB keyboard combo. I'll try that nextime. I did not know about journactl. I'm not familiar with debugging on Linux, that's kinda the point of my post ^^ SSH is not possible, I have no other computer to SSH into

Comment: You can use your phone as a SSH client. REISUB is the same as holding down the power button, except less likely to cause data less.